# Question about tension?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

In a nutshell, what exactly is 'tension' in a string or spring etc, and its properties?

I was wondering this because I read that if you have a spring in equilibrium and you know there is a force $F$ applied to one end, then as it is in equilibrium the net force in any point in the spring is 0 and therefore the force F is trnasmitted through the spring and there must be an equal and opposite force on the other end.

According to Wikipedia, tension is also an 'action-reaction pair'. If this is so, and at any point in the string/spring in equilibrium the net force is zero, then how come at ome end of the string/spring we cut off these reaction pairs such that we have a net force in one direction, and at the other end of the string it is cut off to be in exactly the opposite direction? Thinking about infintesimally small string sections, I don't see how an action reaction pair at every point can lead to a net force at each end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a string and hold it tight between your hands. And just hold it there. Tight.

No net force on any piece of the string, of course. But a net force at the ends? **Also no**! Otherwise they would move (accelerate).

Here is the line of thought:

- One hand pulls in one end. Since that end doesn't move, the pulling force must be balanced. So the next piece of the string holds on to the end piece with the exact same force as the pull.
- This next piece *also* doesn't move. But Newton's third law says that when that piece holds on to the end piece with a force, then it feels this force itself in the opposite direction! This is the **action-reaction** force pair. So while pulling in the end piece with the same pulling force in order to hold on to it, it is *itself* pulled in with that same pulling force. But it stays still because *the third* piece holds on to it with the same force as the pulling force in order to balance it.
- Again Newton's third law says that this third piece should also be pulled forward by this same holding force (which is still the same as the original pulling force from the hand). But it *doesn't* move, since it is balanced by the *fourth* piece holding on to it with the same force as the pulling force.
- etc...
- The second last piece in the string is by this chain-logic also pulled in with the same force as the pulling force in the first end. Just like all the other pieces are. And the last piece holds on to it with the same force, to balance it.
- This last piece is by Newton's third law (as all the others) pulled forward by that very same force. It doesn't move because your other hand is there to pull oppositely and balance it.

So, all on all: each piece of the string feels a pull and a counter-pull - an equal pull in each direction - and the pulls "progress" from piece to piece by Newton's third law. Which brings in the talk about action-reaction pairs.

Comment: Will this hold when they are accelerated?

Comment: @harambe You could do a similar line of thought when edge piece accelerates at the same acceleration, yes. A force pair from Newton's 3rd law  always exists, regardless.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the net force at any point on the spring must be zero when the spring is in equilibrium - if it were not zero, something would have to be moving. This is always the case any time you're considering different forces acting on an object - if the net force works out to be non-zero, then the object must be moving.

As for the ends of the spring: let's say you're holding one end of the spring in each hand and stretching it. The net force is still zero at every point on the spring, including the very ends. That's because the ends of the spring are not free in this situation - you're holding on to them. The balancing force comes from your hands - in equilibrium, your hands are supplying a force that exactly balances the tension in the spring (which wants to pull the spring back together).

If you want to know what happens to the forces purely in the spring with no external forces, just let go of the spring. In this case, the tension in the spring is not balanced by any external force, and so the net force at the ends of the spring, and at all other points along the spring too, are no longer zero. With non-zero net force, the ends of the spring move together due to the tension in the spring.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Let me see if I got this right: so when I stretch a spring applying an outwards force F at each end, then if I consider my hands they are experiencing an inwards force from the spring and an outwards force from my muscles. When I let go I no longer hand an inwards force on my hands (and it takes some time for my muscles to respond so my hands do accelerate and decelerate outwards a bit). Now considering the spring, the end points of the pring experience the force F from my hands and an equal and opposite force F inwards from the rest f the spring (and this is the

Comment: 'tension'. At each point in the spring the atoms there must also experience a force F outwards from their neighbouring atoms. Now when I let go the outer ends of the spring now have a net inwards force (due to tension in the spring), and as the outer ends come closer to the atoms that are not at the very outer ends then the outwards force from them decreases, so you have a net inwards force F that propagates from out to in through the spring in a 'slinky' manner to compress the spring again.

Answer (score 1):

Tension is the force which a spring or elastic body exerts on an object it is in contact with or attached to.

If the spring or elastic string is not accelerating then you are correct in saying that the net force on each segment of it is zero. Each segment is pulled equally in opposite directions by the adjacent segments. For a spring which is accelerating at rate $a$, or which has weight, the net force on each segment is its mass times $a$ or $g$ as appropriate, according to Newton's 2nd Law.

Action-reaction pairs (Newton's 3rd Law) are equal and oppositely-directed forces which act **on different bodies** or segments of bodies. The tension in the spring is transmitted from one segment to the next adjacent segment, all the way along the spring. At the ends of the spring/string there are no adjacent segments to act on - the action-reaction pairs are between the end segments and the body they are in contact with.

Answer (score 0):

An action-reaction pair has only the same magnitude of $|F|$ and $|-F|$ if this pair acts exactly on the same point. When taking free-body diagrams on infinitesimal segments of the string, where on the right acts a force $F(x+dx)$ and on the left acts the force $-F(x)$, summing up yields:

$F_{net}(x) = F(x+dx)-F(x) \approx \partial_xF(x)dx$.

Answer (score 0):

The spring force distributed along a spring or tension along a string is an electrostatic force: repulsion between electrons and attraction between electrons and nuclei.    We can see that this must be true because among the four known forces in the universe, the only other candidates are the strong force and weak force, which are strictly internal to the nuclei of atoms, and gravitational force, which is 10^37 weaker than the electromagnetic force.

Newton's third law holds at any point or plane along the length of the spring or string which is not accelerating.    Newton's third law also holds at the ends of the spring.   There cannot be any force at the ends that is not matched by a force in the opposite direction.   In other words, the ends must be attached to other objects.     All forces are interactions between two objects.